# Ruby on Rails creating a new doubly nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So currently I have a nested project. It starts with floors=>switches=>jacks. I have everything working up through trying to create a new jack. When I am in the switch show there is an open field for a new jack and a create button. When I type in the jack number and hit create is when the error arises. Assuming all other code is correct (let me know if you want to see any other code), what is wrong with my create method in my jacks controller?

apps/controllers/jacks_controller.rb:

```
  ...
  def create
    @floor = Floor.find(params[:floor_id])
    @switch = @floor.switches.find(params[:switch_id])
    @jack = @switch.jacks.create(params[:jack])
    redirect_to(@switch)
  end
  ...
```

The error it gives me is "No route matches [POST] "/floors/1/switches/1" ". This also makes no sense to me because that is the exact URL for the current switch I'm adding jacks to.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can explain what I'm doing wrong or my misunderstanding!

EDIT:

Here is my rake routes:

```
    floor_switch_jacks GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks(.:format)          jacks#index
                       POST   /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks(.:format)          jacks#create
 new_floor_switch_jack GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/new(.:format)      jacks#new
edit_floor_switch_jack GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/:id/edit(.:format) jacks#edit
     floor_switch_jack GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/:id(.:format)      jacks#show
                       PUT    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/:id(.:format)      jacks#update
                       DELETE /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/:id(.:format)      jacks#destroy
        floor_switches GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches(.:format)                           switches#index
                       POST   /floors/:floor_id/switches(.:format)                           switches#create
      new_floor_switch GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/new(.:format)                       switches#new
     edit_floor_switch GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:id/edit(.:format)                  switches#edit
          floor_switch GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:id(.:format)                       switches#show
                       PUT    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:id(.:format)                       switches#update
                       DELETE /floors/:floor_id/switches/:id(.:format)                       switches#destroy
                floors GET    /floors(.:format)                                              floors#index
                       POST   /floors(.:format)                                              floors#create
             new_floor GET    /floors/new(.:format)                                          floors#new
            edit_floor GET    /floors/:id/edit(.:format)                                     floors#edit
                 floor GET    /floors/:id(.:format)                                          floors#show
                       PUT    /floors/:id(.:format)                                          floors#update
                       DELETE /floors/:id(.:format)                                          floors#destroy
            home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                                          home#index
                  root        /                                                              home#index
```

Is this good for the routes.rb? Otherwise my routes.rb is very basic, haven't touched it much at all. If that's where my problem is, could you help or send me to a tutorial that doesn't gloss over the routes.rb part?

EDIT:

I fixed it. The problem was in the form for line in my jacks/_form.html.erb. The correct syntax was:

```
<%= form_for [@floor, @switch, @switch.jacks.new]  do |f| %>
```

Thanks to anyone who tried to help, it was appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your routes.rb file?  If you can browse to /floors/1/switches/1 but can't post there, that sounds like a routing issue.

Comment: Well, I don't see any route that looks like `POST /floors/:floor_id/switches/:id`, which is what the error is saying doesn't exist.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm trying to use jacks like I did switches, but it doesn't work the same way with my current route configuration. Is there any way I can either add that route or use an existing route to add a new jack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running into a similar situation and solved it by changing my `redirect_to` statement.  Try something like this:

```
redirect_to [@floor, @switch]
```

At the time I remember that the error message did not help me out, it was in fact throwing me off the trail.

All your routes start with `/floor`, but I believe

```
redirect_to @switch
```

Will try to resolve to a `/switch` path, which you don't have defined.

Comment: Did this work?  If this answer solved your problem, it would help others who might run into something similar if you marked it as accepted. Thx.

Comment: Hey sorry, I've been gone since Thursday and haven't had much time to work on it.

    No, it did not work, I'm still having the same problem. I tried the new redirect_to and I'm still getting:

No route matches [POST] "/floors/1/switches/1"

Comment: I got it to work! Believe me, I did search beforehand, but now I did fine a similar situation to mine and I fixed it. I'll edit the main post for info.